# Java: Como girar imágenes dentro de un Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, interfaz-gráfica

Buen día compañeros

En el avance de mi proyecto deseo girar estas imágenes de los tanques que se encuentran dentro de un Canvas, quiero que cuando mueva el tanque hacia arriba me gire 90 grados o si lo muevo hacia la derecha me gire 180 grado y así respectivamente según la dirección

Estas son las imágenes que deseo que se giren

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código con el cual estoy cargando las imagenes de los tanques dentro del Canvas

```
public class Tanque {

private BufferedImage imagenTanque1;
private BufferedImage imagenTanque2;
private int ancho;
private int alto;
private int posx;
private int posy;

public Tanque(int ancho, int alto, int x, int y){
    this.ancho=ancho;
    this.alto=alto;
    this.posx=x;
    this.posy=y; 
    try {
        // A modo de ejemplo, puse la imagen en el C:, sin embargo podrías agregarla a tu proyecto, o buscarla en otro directorio
        this.imagenTanque1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Dropbox\\EAM Ingenieria de Software\\Sistemas Distribuidos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\src\\recursos\\tank1.jpg"));
        this.imagenTanque2 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Dropbox\\EAM Ingenieria de Software\\Sistemas Distribuidos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\src\\recursos\\tank2.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        this.imagenTanque1 = null;
        this.imagenTanque2 = null;
    }
}


public BufferedImage getImagenTanque1() {       
    return this.imagenTanque1;
}

public BufferedImage getImagenTanque2() {
    return this.imagenTanque2;
}
/**
 * @return the ancho
 */
public int getAncho() {
    return ancho;
}

/**
 * @param ancho the ancho to set
 */
public void setAncho(int ancho) {
    this.ancho = ancho;
}

/**
 * @return the alto
 */
public int getAlto() {
    return alto;
}

/**
 * @param alto the alto to set
 */
public void setAlto(int alto) {
    this.alto = alto;
}

/**
 * @return the posx
 */
public int getPosx() {
    return posx;
}

/**
 * @param posx the posx to set
 */
public void setPosx(int posx) {
    this.posx = posx;
}

/**
 * @return the posy
 */
public int getPosy() {
    return posy;
}

/**
 * @param posy the posy to set
 */
public void setPosy(int posy) {
    this.posy = posy;
}
```

}

Este es el código con el cual puedo mover las imágenes

```
public class JFrameJuegoBase extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private CanvasDibujable canvas = null;
    private Cliente cliente;

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrameJuego
     */
    public JFrameJuegoBase() {
        initComponents();
//        CanvasDibujable canvas = new CanvasDibujable(){
//            public void paint(Graphics g){
//                try{
//                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("recursos/fondoPasto.jpg"));
//                    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
//                } catch (IOException ex) {
//                   ex.printStackTrace();
//                }
//            }
//        };
        //Image imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("fondoPasto")).getImage();
        canvas = new CanvasDibujable();
       canvas.setBounds(30,30,720,600);
       canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        this.add(canvas);       
        cliente=new Cliente();  
//        PanelFondo pnlFondo = new PanelFondo();
//        pnlFondo.setjFramePadre(this);
       // this.add(pnlFondo,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      //  this.pack();

    }



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 700));
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Jugador Remoto");

        jLabel2.setText("Jugador Local");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(831, 831, 831)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 807, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverDerecha(getCanvas(),getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("derecha"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverIzquierda(getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("izquierda"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverArriba(getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("arriba"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverAbajo(getCanvas(),getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("abajo"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                new Thread(new HiloBala(canvas.getControladorBala(),
                        new Tanque(10,10,
                                canvas.getControladorTanque().getTanque1().getPosx(),
                                canvas.getControladorTanque().getTanque1().getPosy())
                        ,canvas)).start();
                //envian 
                break;    
        }
    }
```

Estas son las imágenes que voy colocar cada vez que se mueva en un sentido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera estoy cargando los tanques en el JFrame

```
public class JFrameJuegoBase extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private CanvasDibujable canvas = null;
    private Cliente cliente;

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrameJuego
     */
    public JFrameJuegoBase() {
        initComponents();
//        CanvasDibujable canvas = new CanvasDibujable(){
//            public void paint(Graphics g){
//                try{
//                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("recursos/fondoPasto.jpg"));
//                    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
//                } catch (IOException ex) {
//                   ex.printStackTrace();
//                }
//            }
//        };
        //Image imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("fondoPasto")).getImage();
        canvas = new CanvasDibujable();
       canvas.setBounds(30,30,720,600);
       canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        this.add(canvas);       
        cliente=new Cliente();  
//        PanelFondo pnlFondo = new PanelFondo();
//        pnlFondo.setjFramePadre(this);
       // this.add(pnlFondo,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      //  this.pack();

    }



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 700));
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Jugador Remoto");

        jLabel2.setText("Jugador Local");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(831, 831, 831)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 807, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverDerecha(getCanvas(),getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("derecha"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverIzquierda(getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("izquierda"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverArriba(getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("arriba"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                getCanvas().getControladorTanque().moverAbajo(getCanvas(),getCanvas().getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
                getCliente().enviarMensaje(new InformacionJugadorRemoto("abajo"));
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                new Thread(new HiloBala(canvas.getControladorBala(),
                        new Tanque(10,10,
                                canvas.getControladorTanque().getTanque1().getPosx(),
                                canvas.getControladorTanque().getTanque1().getPosy())
                        ,canvas)).start();
                //envian 
                break;    
        }
    }                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameJuegoBase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameJuegoBase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameJuegoBase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameJuegoBase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        JFrameJuegoBase frameJuego=new JFrameJuegoBase();
        ExecutorService poolHilos = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        poolHilos.submit(new LectorComandosRemoto(frameJuego.getCliente().getCanalEntrada(), frameJuego.getCanvas()));
        poolHilos.submit(frameJuego.getCanvas());
        poolHilos.submit(() -> {
            frameJuego.setVisible(true);
        });

        /* Create and display the form */
//        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                frameJuego.setVisible(true);
//            }
//        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    /**
     * @return the canvas
     */
    public CanvasDibujable getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cliente
     */
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param canvas the canvas to set
     */
    public void setCanvas(CanvasDibujable canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    /**
     * @param cliente the cliente to set
     */
    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira esta respuesta en SOen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918482/rotating-bufferedimage-instances

Comment: Un método que permite dibujar una imagen girada es `drawImage()` perteneciente a la clase `Graphics2D`. También te puedes ayudar de la clase `AffineTransform` para 'deformar' esa imagen.

Comment: Se puede utilizar una misma imagen, y realizarle el giro. En vez de hacer la sustitución

Comment: Como logro hacer para que la imagen realice el giro ?

Comment: Te voy a dejar un ejemplo en la respuesta con todos los pasos en forma de comentarios en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un par de Clases. Una se encargará del dibujado del lienzo, en este caso el **tanque**, y tendrá un par de métodos para hacer la rotación.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    /**
     * Componente que dibuja una foto y permite rotarla
     * @author Diego L. Ortiz Lopez
     */
    public class Lienzo extends JComponent {
        private ImageIcon icono = null; /** La foto */
        private double rotacion = 0.0; /** Cuanto queremos que se rote la foto, en radianes. */

        /**
         * Devuelve como tamaño preferido el de la foto
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(icono.getIconWidth(), icono.getIconHeight());
        }

        /**
         * Carga la foto y la guarda
         * @param ficheroImagen
         */
        public Lienzo(String ficheroImagen){
            icono = new ImageIcon(ficheroImagen);
        }

        /**
         * Dibujo de la foto rotándola
         */
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            // AffineTransform realiza el giro, usando como eje de giro el centro de la foto (width/2, height/2)
            // y el ángulo que indica el atributo rotación.
            AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotacion, icono.getIconWidth()/2, icono.getIconHeight()/2);
            // dibujado con la AffineTransform de rotación
            g2d.drawImage(icono.getImage(), tx, this);      
        }

        /**
         * Devuelve la rotación actual.
         * @return rotación en radianes
         */
        public double getRotacion(){
            return rotacion;
        }

        /**
         * Se le pasa la rotación deseada.
         * @param rotacion La rotación en radianes
         */
        public void setRotacion(double rotacion){
            this.rotacion = rotacion;
        }

    }
```

---

Y otra donde la mandamos a llamar en un marco.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * Ejemplo de giro de gráfico.
 * Una ventana con una foto y dos botones para girar en sentido horario y antihorario
 * @author Diego L. Ortiz Lopez
 */
public class GirarImagen {
    private Lienzo lienzo; /** Componente que lleva la foto */
    private Tanque tanque;

    /** 
     * Método para crear nuestra GUI y pasarlo al constructor
     * Crea la ventana, los botones y lo pone todo en marcha
     */
    private void muestraGUI() {
        //Construcción de la ventana.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame marco = new JFrame("Girar gráfico");
        marco.setLocation(300, 300);
        marco.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        //Componente con la foto
        lienzo = new Lienzo("datosEjemplos/goku2.png");
        marco.getContentPane().add(lienzo);
        //El tanque
        tanque = new Tanque(200,200, "datosEjemplos/tanque.png");
        tanque.setSize(100,100);
        marco.getContentPane().add(tanque, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Panel con los botones
        JPanel botonesRotacion = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton botonSentidoHorario = new JButton("+0.1");
        JButton botonSentidoAntiHorario = new JButton("-0.1");
        botonesRotacion.add(botonSentidoAntiHorario);
        botonesRotacion.add(botonSentidoHorario);
        marco.getContentPane().add(botonesRotacion, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //Acciones de los botones
        botonSentidoAntiHorario.addActionListener((e) -> {
            lienzo.setRotacion(lienzo.getRotacion() - 0.1);
            lienzo.repaint();
            tanque.setRotacion(tanque.getRotacion() - 1.57);//90 grados - '180º 3,14'  '360º 6,283
            tanque.repaint();
        });
        botonSentidoHorario.addActionListener((e) -> {
            lienzo.setRotacion(lienzo.getRotacion() + 0.1); //
            lienzo.repaint();
            tanque.setRotacion(tanque.getRotacion() + 1.57);//90 grados - '180º 3,14'  '360º 6,283
            tanque.repaint();
        });

        //Visualizar todo.
        marco.pack();
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marco.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Crea la ventana, los botones y lo pone todo en marcha
     */
    public GirarImagen() {
        muestraGUI();
    }

    /**
     * Crea una instancia de esta clase
     * @param args 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new GirarImagen();
        });
    }


}
```

---

## Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

P.d. Fuente [AffineTransform: Rotación de un gráfico o imagen en java](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=AffineTransform:_Rotaci%C3%B3n_de_un_gr%C3%A1fico_o_imagen_en_java)

Comment: Lo que quiero es hacerlo girar al presionar la tecla ya sea flecha a un lado o flecha abajo se me gire la imagen

Comment: Pues tendrás que hacer la captura del evento en la susodicha tecla, en vez de como lo he implementado en los botones. El Escuchador `KeyListener`, y el Adaptador `KeyAdapter`, que implementan los métodos `keyPressed(KeyEvent)`- `keyReleased(KeyEvent)` - `keyTyped(KeyEvent)`.

Comment: Revisa la pregunta, voy a agregar el JFrame donde estoy moviendo el tanque en un solo sentido y tengo unos eventos con KeyEvent

Comment: A ver si mañana le puedo echar un vistazo con más detenimiento a tu código.

Comment: Revisaste el codigo

Comment: Si lo hice. Si quieres hacerlo más funcional tienes que utilizar `drawImage()` perteneciente a la clase `Graphics2D`. Y añadir una variable para la rotación y poder setearla. Pero hay que rediseñar bastante.